# Javascript: Call C# codebehind string function but return all HTML of current page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, pagemethods

I am using PageMethods to call C# function from Javascript.

My C# function is return as String.
But after i called that function from Javascript it returned current page.

Here my code:

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <script>
        function testPageMethods(){
            var id = 45;
            PageMethods.returnStr4Frontend(id, onSucess, onError);
        }
        function onSucess(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
        function onError(result) {
            console.log(has error);
        }

        testPageMethods();
        </script>
</form>
```

ASPX.CS

```
[WebMethod]
public static string returnStr4Frontend(string id)
{
    string reStr = string.Empty;

    reStr = "Your id is: " + id;

    return reStr;
}
```

When i run my page on browser, i received wrong result was (all html code of current page):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <script>
        function testPageMethods(){
            var id = 45;
            PageMethods.returnStr4Frontend(id, onSucess, onError);
        }
        function onSucess(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
        function onError(result) {
            console.log(has error);
        }

        testPageMethods();
        </script>
</form>
```

Comment: I want to receive: Your id is: 45

Answer (score 0):

Check this nugget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

it will get the html code depending on the domain you entered